# Proof and Intuition for $\partial_{q-1}\circ \partial_{q} = 0$ for $q\ge 2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am reading *Singular Homology* from Tammo Tom Dieck's *Algebraic Topology*. The author introduces the boundary operator $\partial_q$, and notes the boundary relation $\partial_{q-1}\circ \partial_{q} = 0$ for $q\ge 2$. I need help with the proof of this result and would appreciate it if anyone could provide some intuition behind it.

Here is the context (paraphrased) from the book (Pg. $224$, Section $9.1$, Chapter $9$: Singular Homology):

> Let $\delta_i^n: [n-1]\to [n]$ be the (weakly increasing) injective map which misses the value $i$. This induces an affine map $d_i^n = \triangle(\delta_i^n): \triangle[n-1]\to \triangle [n]$, where $\triangle[n]$ denotes the standard $n$-simplex embedded in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. Note that $\delta_j^{n+1}\delta_i^n = \delta_i^{n+1} \delta_{j-1}^n$ for $i < j$. This gives $d_j^{n+1}d_i^n = d_i^{n+1} d_{j-1}^n$ for $i < j$. A continuous map $\sigma:\triangle^n \to X$ is called a singular $n$-simplex in $X$. The $i$th face of $\sigma$ is $\sigma\circ d_i^n$. $S_n(X)$ is the free abelian group with basis the set of singular $n$-simplices in $X$. The boundary operator $\partial_q: S_q(X)\to S_{q-1}(X)$ is defined for $q\ge 1$ by $\partial_q: \sigma\mapsto \sum_{i=0}^q (-1)^{i} \sigma d_i^q$ and for $q\le 0$ as the zero-map. $\partial_{q-1} \circ \partial_q = 0$ is known as the *boundary* relation.
>  [For more details, see a screenshot from the book here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olDso.jpg)

---

1. **Proof:**
   Here is my attempt, which follows the hint provided in the book. We have \begin{align*}
   \partial_{q-1}\circ \partial_{q}(\sigma) &= \partial_{q-1}\left(\sum_{j=0}^q (-1)^i \sigma d_i^q \right)\\ &= \sum_{j=0}^q (-1)^j \sum_{i=0}^{q-1} (-1)^i (\sigma d_j^q) d_i^{q-1}\\ &= \sum_{j=0}^q \sum_{i=0}^{q-1} (-1)^{i+j} \sigma d_j^q d_i^{q-1}\\ &=
   \sum_{j=0}^q \sum_{i< j} (-1)^{i+j} \sigma d_j^q d_i^{q-1}  + \sum_{j=0}^q \sum_{i\ge j} (-1)^{i+j} \sigma d_j^q d_i^{q-1}\\
   &=  \sum_{j=0}^q \sum_{i< j} (-1)^{i+j} \sigma d_i^q d_{j-1}^{q-1}  + \sum_{j=0}^q \sum_{i\ge j} (-1)^{i+j} \sigma d_j^q d_i^{q-1}\\ &\stackrel{?}{=} 0
   \end{align*}
   Why is this zero? I suppose some change of indices, etc. should show that the first sum is the negative of the second, but I'm not able to do it. Any help would be great.
2. **Intuition:** 
    *Why* should $$\partial_{q-1}\circ \partial_{q} = 0$$ be true? I'm looking for *intuition*, and not formal proof (since that has already been discussed in the first half of this post.)

---

Let me know if any notation is not clear. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do it for the triangle for both intuition and formal insight.

Comment: I agree with the above comment. It's always a good idea to go through simple cases in detail. I would also suggest you try it for  $q=1,2,3$ writing out the various sums in full without  $\sum$ signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, every proof regarding boundary operators of homological theories is just a matter of signs, but how to understand the equality $\partial^2=0$, why is it called boundary operator?

As some comments suggested, you should work out for few simple cases to see what is happening here. For instance, let $X=[e_0,e_1,e_2]$ be a $2$-simplex (a triangle with vertices $e_0,e_1,e_2$), oriented counterclockwise.

[image]

Then $\partial(X) = [e_1,e_2] + [e_2,e_0] + [e_0,e_1]$ and you see that applying $\partial$ gives us three edges which is informally the boundary of $X$ with respect to the given orientation. Moreover,
$$ \partial^2(X) = e_1 - e_2 + e_2 - e_0 + e_0 - e_1 = 0.$$
If moreover you're interested de Rham cohomology then $\partial^2=0$ is a consequence of Schwartz's lemma, asserting that we can change the order of taking derivatives of a multivariable function provided the function is sufficiently nice. In both cases, the slogan here is

*The boundary of a space (manifold, etc) is a space of the same kind without boundary.*

In higher dimensional cases $[e_0,...,e_n]$, the first time you apply the boundary operator, $\partial: \sigma \mapsto \sum (-1)^k\sigma_{\mid [e_1,...,\hat{e_k},...,e_n]}$, you get all the faces opposite to vertices, afterwards, you obtain all "faces of faces" but remember each "faces of faces" appears exactly twice with opposite signs (like $e_0,e_1,e_2$ in our example) due to the orientability and hence all the things cancel out.

Comment: My proof isn't even complete though. Could you help complete it?

Comment: In the first sum, you set $j-1=k$ then $k \geq i$ and the signs are $(-1)^{i+k+1}$.